# Apps script get element by id

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

[image]

I've got the following in an apps script client side html template:

```
<body>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
<div>
    <label for="optionList">Click me</label>
    <select id="optionList" name="email" onchange="optionChange()">
        <option>Loading...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to capture the change using :

```
function optionChange() {
 mySelect = document.getElementById("optionList");
 console.log(mySelect)
 };
```

But I do not see any elements in the console.

Following some other boilerplate code I got from some examples I tried:

```
mySelect = $(document).getElementById("optionList").value;
```

Now in the console I get:

> TypeError: $(...).getElementById is not a function

At least I see something in the console. What is '$' and How can I get this working?

---

I've made the suggested change but still just see spreadsheet related post and get statements in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the value property of the element, so

```
//based on your coding style
function optionChange() {
mySelect = document.getElementById("optionList");
mySelectValue = mySelect.value;
console.log(mySelectValue)
 };
```

or

```
//based on your coding style
function optionChange() {
mySelect = document.getElementById("optionList").value;
console.log(mySelect)
 };
```

Comment: It turned out that this worked in chrome but not firefox. I switched over to chrome to do this part